# Why do I get a document function error on a specific plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm new to this forum

I am using the Avada Wordpress theme.
I have down loaded a plugin - 'Filter Gallery Pro' which is not working correctly on my site - https://www.heritagecentralotago.org.nz/oral-history-catalogue/
The developers of this Plugin tested it on an independent install of Avada (7.10.1) and showed that the plugin works with Avada - see their video link below

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/17654567?key=296ff7dcbcd94f6b375b90fb0fb05520

I have tried deactivating all plugins and cleared the site cache, but this did ot work. There is Jquery error on the console of this page

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at (index):452:2
(anonymous) @ (index):452

I, an intermediate wordpress administrator so any step-by-step help is much appreciated

Kind regards
Maggie

Deactivating Plugins
Clearing cache

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the Tour. Your question is a bit too vague. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just visited the site and don't see such an error in the console.

Comment: @freedomn-m: I had to temporarily delete my answer because looking at the source code again, I noticed that `jQuery` loads in the footer, but **before** the *Filter Gallery Plugin*. So today I had to test it myself on one of my staging sites first. The answer is now back, proofed and improved =)

Answer (score 1):

In AVADA you have the option to load `jQuery` in the `footer`. Turning this feature on **can cause JS scripts to break**. So this sould **always** be used with caution.

After visting your page thru the [link](https://www.heritagecentralotago.org.nz/oral-history-catalogue/) you provided, i can definitely say that `jQuery` is loaded in the footer. Your plugin probably needs to have `jQuery` loaded in the `<head>` section. You can check this yourself in your browser's source code view on line 761.

I had to temporarily delete my answer because looking at the source code again, I noticed that `jQuery` loads in the footer, but **before** the *Filter Gallery Plugin*. So today I had to test it myself on one of my staging sites first. There could be other reasons as well, e.g. *Load Media-Queries Files Asynchronously*, *Enable JS Compiler*, etc. Since I don't have a Pro license, I installed the free version of the plugin. At first I also had the `jQuery` error. However, I was able to solve the problem.

**To fix the issue** go to Avada > Options > Performance (`themes.php?page=avada_options`) and **uncheck option** `Load jQuery In Footer`. To be on the safe side, I also list my other settings.

Avada > Options > Performance:

- SVG Media Upload = **On**
- WordPress Image Quality = **85**
- WordPress Big Image Size Threshold= **2560**
- Image Lazy Loading = **Avada**
- Iframe Lazy Loading = **Avada**
- Font Face Rendering = **Swap All**
- Preload Key Fonts = **None**
- Emojis Script = **Disable**
- **jQuery Migrate Script = Disable** (!)
- **Load jQuery In Footer = Off** (!)
- Load Stylesheets In Footer = **Off**
- Enable Gzip Compression = **Off**
- Enable Video Facade = **Off**
- **Clear Object Cache = On** (!)
- CSS Compiling Method = **File**
- Combine Third Party CSS Files = **On**
- **Load Media-Queries Files Asynchronously = Off** (!)
- Enable Critical CSS = **Off**
- **Enable JS Compiler = On** (!)